# If statement, compare one variable to multiple

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

Example:

```
int value = someValue;
if (value == (valueOne OR valueTwo OR valueThree)){
//do code
}
```

I would like to avoid re-typing `value` like in my example below.

```
if (value == valueOne || value == valueTwo || value == valueThree)
```

Comment: You use `||` to do boolean OR comparison. The single bar, `|` is used for bit operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `||` to do boolean OR comparison. The single bar, `|` is used for bit operations. Your current syntax is incorrect.

```
if(value ==1 || value==2 || value ==3)
```

Of course, it might be better to do a range check here like so:

```
if(value>=1 && value<=3)
```

Not sure what you're trying to do though.

If the OR comparison makes more sense for you here, you should define some constants for these values, or consider an enumerated type.  The literals 1, 2, and 3 have no meaning to other developers.

Comment: I originally put 1,2,3 for simplicity of asking the question. I don't need a range. I was wanting to avoid re-typing `value` for each comparison, though if I must, that is okay.

Comment: @Jakar Yeah, the syntax is a little lengthy. A switch statement would prevent retyping `value`, but its wordy too.  There's not really a less verbose way of doing this type of simple comparison.

Comment: Okay. That's kind of what I figured, but I believe I had seen something in another language like what I wanted, so I figured it was worth asking.

Comment: Technically, there are ways to do what you want without retyping 'value', as you requested.  if(Arrays.asList(val1, val2, val3).contains(value)){ //do things}

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with `if` statement in Java, but with the `switch` statement.

```
switch (value) {
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3: {
      //do something
   }
}
```

This will check if the `value` is equal to `1`, `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 4):

This would do it in one check:

```
int value = someValue;
if(Arrays.asList(valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree).contains(someValue)){
    // do the things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [`Range`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) class from apache commons :

```
Range r = Range.between(1,3);
if(r.contains(value)){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using a `HashSet`

```
 Set<Integer> myset = new HashSet<Integer>();
//Add values to your set
if(myset.contains(myvalue));
{
    //... Do what you want.
```

This allows your algorithm to be flexible and not have to manually code in new checks when you want to check against a new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
  == tests for reference equality.

 .equals() tests for value equality.

   //for loop to iterate through the range of values
  if(setofValues.equals( value)) ; // do something
```