# How can one check if an integer is equal to another in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can one check if an integer is equal to another in a 2D array?

```
int[][] board = new int [3][3];
int a = board[0][0];
int b = board[0][1];
int c = board[0][2];
int d = board[1][0];
int e = board[1][1];
int f = board[1][2];
int g = board[2][0];
int h = board[2][1];
int i = board[2][2];
```

I am trying to compare the integer "a" from the 2D array named "int[][]board" with the other variables (b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) to check if "a" is equal to any of them.

I attempted to solve this issue by writing out this:

```
if (a == (b || c || d || e || f || g || h || i))
```

It seems like the operation `||` (known as "or") cannot be used to compare integers. How can I resolve that issue?

Comment: `if (List.of(b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i).contains(a))`.

Comment: Related: [Is there a simpler way to check multiple values against one value in an if-statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8962700/68587), [If statement, compare one variable to multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21194240/68587), and [Best way to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604814/68587).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is iterate through the 2d array and have a boolean to check if it contains the element you are comparing with you could write something as follows:

```
    int number = a;
    boolean check = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // three since you have 3 rows
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++{ // three since you have 3 columns
            if(board[i][j] == number)
                check = true;
        }
    }
```

after these line of codes, you can progress to do as you please with the code

```
if(check){
..... // your code goes here
}
```

However, this will be always true if you try to compare variable "a" since the first element of your array is itself. What you could do for such situtaion is as following:

```
    int number = a;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // three since you have 3 rows
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++{ // three since you have 3 columns
            if(board[i][j] == number)
                count++;
        }
    }

    if(count > 1) {
        .... // your code goes here
    }
```

hope it helped.

Comment: Also you could do board[i][j] == a in the if statement and proceed.

Comment: Won't this always be true, since `a` is present at position `[0][0]` in the array?

Comment: Yes that is true. My code was to compare the values with any other variable. I will edit my answer for the situation you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Just to address your attempt, the correct syntax for that would be

`if (a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e || a == f || a == g || a == h || a == i) ...`.

But depending on your use case, it's probably advisable to loop over the array instead.

Comment: @Erick Lumme Can you also teach me how to do it with a loop?

Comment: It depends on your use case, like do you need to know the index of the number that matches, do you need to know all numbers that match, do you always compare it with the first number etc. The answer by RaffleBuffle looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by writing a general function that checks if the value at a specific position in the array occurs anywhere else:

```
static boolean isDuplicate(int[][] arr, int row, int col)
{
    for(int r=0; r<arr.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<arr[r].length; c++)
        {
            if(arr[r][c] == arr[row][col] && (r != row || c != col))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
int[][] board = {{a,b,c}, {d,e,f}, {g,h,i};
boolean duplicateA = isDuplicate(board, 0, 0);
```